# How to select multiple files with an OpenFileDialog?

Tags: winforms, visual-c++

I have a WinForms application with an OpenFileDialog in it and I'd like to enable selection of multiple files when the user interacts with the dialog. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in Visual Studio or in your own application? If it's the latter, what GUI framework (MFC, Winforms, etc.) are you using?

Comment: i'm using normal visual studio, coding c++, yes i want to know hw to do this in vc++. GUI is Winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding the style OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT will add this [see this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/doc_view/misc/article.php/c6119/)

If you want to select a folder you should use something else :)

If you are using c++ .net (you didn't state that). You can use the MultiSelect property [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

See the [OpenFileDialog::Multiselect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect.aspx) property, from the docs:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the dialog box allows multiple files to be selected.

To get the list of files selected you should use the [OpenFileDialog::FileNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what you did, but when I click File/Open in Visual Studio 2008, it is possible to multi-select all files or just a part of them by clicking on the first file in the list, holding the shift key and then clicking on the last file.

EDIT: ok, you edited the question, seems that I misunderstood you in the first place. Idan K's answer should be correct.

Comment: no not in visual studio IDE please:) its coding, i been using winforms, when i click on fileopen, in my application, a file browser pops up, but i can select only one file, what is logic/code to select multiple images? i can't do control-a, then open, one file opens and copies into buffer?

Answer (score 2):

C# code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
     ofd.MultiSelect = true; //sets to multiple selects
     ofd.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: should be 
ofd.Multiselect = true;